# A better way to manage questions about rooting particular devices

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm finding it frustrating (to say the least) to find a definitive and up-to-date set of instructions for rooting my phone. The problem I'm having is exactly what StackExchange excels at solving. [This handy collection of links to rooting instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) is certainly valuable, but why not have a separate question for every device and let the voting and comments guide us in finding and choosing the best instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be valuable to expand our current question to include version numbers.  The "gingerbreak" exploit has been fixed in newer versions of 2.3, for example.

I think having a separate question for each device would get out of hand, however.  That list has 50ish devices, which would basically mean 50 times the upkeep if they were split up.  I do understand your point about voting, but I think the community can be trusted to remove terrible instructions, add disclaimers, and add newer/better instructions.

If there are unique circumstances, e.g., something that should work for your device and version does not or softbricks your device or something, you can absolutely ask a separate question about that.  So far the wiki has been pretty useful in keeping all of the basic questions from cluttering the site and being harder to find, though -- there are 69 dupes.

Several of us who are familiar with XDA and other sites frequent [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25).  I and I'm sure others would gladly try to help you find the info you're looking for if you give us the details.  The other method to try to solicit this information is through a bounty on the wiki question stating what you need.

As for the problem at hand: Have you tried following the guides listed at the top of [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1067813)?  In particular, some variant of Koush's (flashing recovery and then a rooting package or a rooted ROM) should work regardless of your software version, since the Nexus S has an unlockable bootloader.

Comment: Is there another logical way to break it up? By manufacturer perhaps? Are the instructions for multiple Samsung phones close enough to make it worthwhile?

Comment: @AlEverett I don't think so, though I haven't gone through all 50 guides myself.